# Updating an array in a html file with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

in the script I'm running in Python, I want to open a local html file which has a javascript array inside a script tag which I want to update.

This is a test code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<script>
    var myArray = [
        {'name':'Michael', 'age':'30', 'birthdate':'11/10/1989'},
        {'name':'Mila', 'age':'32', 'birthdate':'10/1/1989'},
        {'name':'Paul', 'age':'29', 'birthdate':'10/14/1990'},
        {'name':'Dennis', 'age':'25', 'birthdate':'11/29/1993'},
        {'name':'Tim', 'age':'27', 'birthdate':'3/12/1991'},
        {'name':'Erik', 'age':'24', 'birthdate':'10/31/1995'},
    ]
    
    buildTable(myArray)
   '''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
scripts = soup.find_all('script')  # successfully captures the <script> element
for script in scripts:
   print(script)
```

I don't know how to select the myArray variable and update it with a different one (which I have in my script)

Comment: You cannot select the `myArray` variable directly since it is Javascript, and BeautifulSoup only parses HTML. So everything inside `script` will be processed as raw text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select the `myArray` variable directly since it is Javascript, and BeautifulSoup only parses HTML. So everything inside `<script>` will be processed as raw text.

That means if you want to update the `<script>` tag, you need to use something like regex as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

newArray = [
       {'name':'Bobby', 'age':'29', 'birthdate':'11/11/1988'}
    ]


html = '''
<script>
    var myArray = [
        {'name':'Michael', 'age':'30', 'birthdate':'11/10/1989'},
        {'name':'Mila', 'age':'32', 'birthdate':'10/1/1989'},
        {'name':'Paul', 'age':'29', 'birthdate':'10/14/1990'},
        {'name':'Dennis', 'age':'25', 'birthdate':'11/29/1993'},
        {'name':'Tim', 'age':'27', 'birthdate':'3/12/1991'},
        {'name':'Erik', 'age':'24', 'birthdate':'10/31/1995'},
    ]
    
    buildTable(myArray)
   '''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
scripts = soup.find_all('script')  # successfully captures the <script> element
for script in scripts:
   script.string = re.sub(r"(myArray.*)\[[^\]]*\]", r"\1" + str(newArray), script.string)

print(soup)

# <html><head><script>
#    var myArray = [{'name': 'Bobby', 'age': '29', 'birthdate': '11/11/1988'}]
#
#    buildTable(myArray)
#   </script></head></html>
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is what I needed